# How to access printer?

Tags: printer

All PC s are connected to router for the purpose of internet. server is located at a distance. HP Laser jet P 1007 printer is connected to a client PC. 
Can other client PC send MS word printing job to this printer? How?

Comment: Yes, You can share the printer from the pc where it is connected to. Also besides being on the same network you need to set up a workgroup and include all computers. They'll be able to print only when the pc connected to the printer is switched on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!
Go to control panel > devices and printers > right click on your printer and choose "share"

[image]

Note: All devices must be at the same network type Public/Home-group/workplace. Also you should activate sharing and network discovery from network and sharing settings, Go to:
Control Panel > network and sharing center > change advance sharing settings > Turn on network discovery and sharing files and printers from there.

Now to access a printer from other PC go to My Computer > Network 
Find the PC that have the printer attached to it, If you can see the printer then everything work perfectly.

To print a file throw MS word or other program go to printer setting from inside the program and choose printer over network from there, some progrmas requare to setup the printer from outside so go to control panel > Devices and printer > add printer > and choose printer over network "or IP" complete the setting to setup the driver..

**NOTE:** The PC that have the printer attached to it will act like a printer server in the network! So it must be ON Always.

You can connect the printer into the network directly without a PC by printer server like this one below,

**Be sure if the device support your printer before you buy anything!**
[image]

Comment: Be careful when suggestion printservers for host-based printers like the P1007. Unless the printserver specifically supports the printer, you must assume it will NOT work. Always check the printer support list of the printserver. If the printer is not on the list (or if the manufacturer does not supply a list) do not buy it.

Comment: I didn't mean this exact model, I'm just mentioning that he can find a device in the market for his need, but thanks I completely forget about that :)